# TinyMCE submitting raw text with HTML tags

Tags: django, tinymce

I'm using a TinyMCE text area in a form to create a new blog post; when I hit "Submit" I should get redirected to a new blog page with the formatted content I typed into the text area. What I actually get is raw content complete with `<p>`, `<strong>`, etc. tags.

Is something not configured properly? Here is the code:

TinyMCE config in my template `<head>`:

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({ 
        selector:'textarea' 
});
</script>
```

Form with TinyMCE text area:

```
<h1>New post</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="progresstracker-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
```

View with relevant code to process the new blog post:

```
def pt_detail(request, slug):
    ptpost = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/pt_detail.html', {'ptpost': ptpost})

def progresstracker(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/progresstracker.html', {'posts': posts})

def progresstracker_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ptpost = form.save(commit=False)
            ptpost.author = request.user
            ptpost.published_date = timezone.now()
            ptpost.save()
            return redirect('pt_detail', slug=ptpost.slug)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, slug):
    ptpost = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=ptpost)
        if form.is_valid():
            ptpost = form.save(commit=False)
            ptpost.author = request.user
            ptpost.published_date = timezone.now()
            ptpost.save()
            return redirect('pt_detail', slug=ptpost.slug)

    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=ptpost)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: If you would like to get a helpful answer than please share the code.

Comment: Is the code I posted enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went down a rabbit hole with tinyMCE and Javascript functions, media references and the like, and in the end solved my problem when I (1) went back to very simple tinyMCE code (per below), and (2) added "|safe" to the actual references to the tinyMCE text.

## template

```
<header>
.
.
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.3/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({ 
    selector: 'textarea'
});
</script>
</header>

<body>
.
.
    {% for post in posts %} 
        <h3><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
        <p style="font-size: 16px">{{ post.published_date|date:'M d, Y' }}</p>
           {{ post.body|truncatewords:50|safe }}
        <hr></hr>
    {% endfor %}
.
.
</body>
```

Comment: Simplest and most effective solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To get contents from TinyMCE you must use editor function getContent(). I don't know Django but maybe you should use a hidden text input in which contents of TinyMCE are saved:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({ 
        selector:'textarea.my_css' 
    });

    function saveContent() {
        var ed = tinymce.activeEditor;
        $('#hidContents').val(ed.getContent());
    }
</script>

<h1>New post</h1>
<form method="POST" class="progresstracker-form">{% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" onclick="saveContent">Save</button>
     <input id="hidContents" type="hidden" name="hidContents">
</form>
```

Recommendations:

- use the latest version (v4.4.3) of TinyMCE
- always use more specific selector so that you are sure you are using the right textarea - example: `selector: 'textarea.my_css'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried your code and when I hit "Save" it takes me to a page with no text (I'm assuming everything was hidden by the code). Any idea how I actually show the text, whether bolded, italicized, etc.. or not?